# Creating a neighborhood base of a point using a given base for a metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

*It is given that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for the metric space $(X,d)$. Now our claim is that $\mathcal{A}=\{G\in\mathcal{B}| a\in G\}$ forms a neighborhood base of $a$, where $a\in X$.*

***The attempted justification of the claim:***

$\mathcal{A}\neq \emptyset$ is an easy observation. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $a$. Then $U=\bigcup\{G_\lambda|\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ for some subcollection $\{G_\lambda|\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ $(\subseteq\mathcal{B})$. *(Here I am taking the neighborhoods of a point to be open sets containing that point).*
Thus $G_\lambda{_0}\subseteq U$ for some $\lambda_0\in\Lambda$. Hence $\mathcal{A}$ is a neighborhood base of $a$.

Is the above "justification" a *justification*?

Comment: If you change $G_{\lambda0}\subset U$ to $a\in G_{\lambda0}$, then it would be correct.

Comment: By default $a\in G_\lambda{_0}$ is true, isn't it? What I've tried to prove is that for any neighborhood of $a$, there is a neighborhood of $a$ in $\mathcal{A}$ which is contained in the aforementioned neighborhood of $a$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong. When you say $\lbrace G_{\lambda}|\lambda\in\Lambda\rbrace$ in $\mathcal{A}$ you're using the claim. So you need to say it's in $\mathcal{B}$ and then $a\in U\implies\exists \lambda_{0}:a\in G_{\lambda_{0}}$ and then $G_{\lambda_0}\in\mathcal{A}$